# Как переместить элемент массива?

Tags: javascript

```
var arr_ = [1,2,3,4];

var oldPlace = 0;
var newPlace = 2;
```

Чтобы массив принял вид:
    [2,1,3,4];

То есть мы берем элемент под индексом 0, вытаскиваем его из массива и вставляем в указанный индекс 2 этого же массива. Вставляем перед указанным индексом.

Comment: Если вы можете писать в существующий элемент массива, то перемена значений местами делается через сохранение значения во временной переменной.

Comment: что ожидается от обратного случая? например от `var oldPlace = 2; var newPlace = 0;` или `var oldPlace = 2; var newPlace = 1;` ?

Comment: @manking странно, галочкой помечен ответ, который в результате делает не то, что описано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4];

const swapArray = function(arr, oldPlace, newPlace) {
    // Проверим выход за пределы массива
    if((Math.min(oldPlace, newPlace) < 0) || (Math.max(oldPlace, newPlace) >= arr.length)) {
      console.error('Out of range')
      return null;
    }
    const item = arr.splice(oldPlace, 1);
    arr.splice((newPlace > 0)? newPlace-1: 0, 0, item[0])
    return arr;
}


console.dir(swapArray(arr, 0, 2));
console.dir(swapArray(arr, 2, 0));
```

Обратите внимание, функция изменяет исходный массив! Можно сделать "безопасную" функцию:

```js
  const arr = [1,2,3,4];

    const safeSwapArray = function(inputArr, oldPlace, newPlace) {
        const arr = inputArr.slice();   // Копируем массив
        // Проверим выход за пределы массива
        if((Math.min(oldPlace, newPlace) < 0) || (Math.max(oldPlace, newPlace) >= arr.length)) {
          console.error('Out of range')
          return null;
        }
        const item = arr.splice(oldPlace, 1);
        arr.splice((newPlace > 0)? newPlace-1: 0, 0, item[0])
        return arr;
    }


    console.dir(safeSwapArray(arr, 0, 2));
    console.dir(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr_ = [1,2,3,4];
 var oldPlace = 0;
var newPlace = 2;

var t = arr_.splice(oldPlace,1);
//после того как удалите элемент из массива, у него изменится длина
arr_.splice(newPlace-1,0,t[0]);
console.log(arr_)
```

Comment: я чуток изменил код, с учетом oldPlace  и newPlace. Но, если newPlace будет 0, то нужно добавить проверку `if - else`

Comment: странно что ответ плюсуют.....а ведь он неверный..например сделайте так `var oldPlace = 2;
var newPlace = 0;` - что получится?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я же отметил, что если `newPlace=0`, то нужно дополнительную проверку делать

Comment: Так а какая разница  0 он или нет? Ну вот другие входные `var oldPlace = 3;
var newPlace = 1;` .....должно быть вроде как `[1, 4, 2, 3]` а получается `[4, 1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, все зависит от задач. Человек задал вопрос, и указал желаемый результат - с теми вводными данными - ожидаемого результата не получилось бы, поэтому из нового индекса пришлось вычесть 1.  Если итоговый результат должен быть другим - настройте код на этот результат.

Comment: Пользуйтесь правкой и дополняйте ваш ответ. В комментариях вы уже больше написали, чем в ответе.